# Using AUCtex on ElementaryOS using Emacs24.2

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm using ElemantaryOS which is an unofficial derivative of Ubuntu. I'm also using Emacs24.2 (There are some shell features that are essentials for me). I tried to install AUXtex (from package manager) however when I added the lines

```
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
```

to `~/.emacs~~, Emacs complained that it can't find`auctex.el``. I tried the naive solution:

```
cp /etc/emacs23/site-start.d/50auxtex.el /etc/emacs/site-start.d/
```

without any luck. I also tried to remove the 50 from the file name with the same result.

What else can I do?

Comment: I added them to ~/.emacs

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant. I also assume that your use of `auxtex` instead of `auctex` in your question is a typo and you have the correct line in your `.emacs`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: In that case, please edit and correct your question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the [11.87 version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+package/auctex) (instead 11.86 from the repos) and now things work.